# JointJS Add Port on click

Tags: jointjs

I'm looking to add half-circle ports in JointJS programmatically when clicking on a port-like "add" button, like so:
[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLz9X.png)

I've created basic ports, and it looks like I could use `element.addPort(port, [opt])`
 but I'm not sure how I'd trigger a click event inside the rectangle element to add the port. The styling of the add button and ports is also something that I'm still trying to recreate with Joint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following these steps should help you:

1. First of all, you have to **create an element with custom HTML** over it. You can achieve it by extending the joint.shapes.devs.Model. You can find a great tutorial about it here: http://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements
2. Then you have to **define a custom port** as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31650340/4109477 (hint: the SVG path of a half-circle is: 
   d="M100,100 a20,20 0 0,0 40,0")
3. Finally you just have to **call the *element.addPort(port, [opt])* function** when your button in your custom HTML element is clicked.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks Frakas! I'm seeing an issue where creating the custom HTML over the element is preventing me from using the drag handle that the standard element had. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: You have to add `pointer-events: none;` style to your main HTML to make sure events are propagated to the JointJS element so, e.g. dragging works. If you would like to interact with some part of the HTML in the "usual" way, for example you want to be able to click on a button which is on your JointJs element, you have to set its(only the button's) style to _pointer-events: auto;_